# Calculate rate in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, formulas, rate

I need to calculate the rate of infection per patient from a report. This report returns the number of months the patient had a catheter and the number of infections they had during this time.

What i need to do is add a column at the end that displays the infection rate per patient.  For example, if a patient has had a catheter in for 12 month and they have had 2 infections, the rate is 2:12 or 1:6.

How do i create this in Crystal Reports?  Not used it much so learning.

Cheers,

Mike D

Edit: The data is from a MySQL database that holds all patient information. I extracted the date that the catheter was inserted as well as the date it was removed and the nunber of infections the patient had during this time. I then used MySQL to calculate the number of months it was in from those two fields.
No I need to calculate  (with MySQL or Crystal) the rate of infection per month.

For example, a patient has a catheter for 12 months and has 2 infections, the rate is 2:12 or 1:6.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Is this a calculation or database field

Comment: @Siva - thanks for your comment. Updated the original post

Comment: If you already have the number of months each catheter was in as well as the number of infections for that time period in your database what is preventing you from just using simple division to get the rate? What am I missing?

Comment: I can, but i am unsure how to code it.  Maybe getting it right in MySQL is a better idea.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit complex report.

First group by patient that will be group 1

Group 2 will be date

Detail part will be list of infections for that patient as recorded in database

You can take the count of dates that is group2 count and count of infections and display in group 1 as required...you can manipulate in the format you need.

If you dont need then you can just display group 1 and supress group2 and details.

Let me know after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Concordinate your data from the database and try formula in cyrstal reports or try doing all the back end calculative steps in SQl and just use the reports to show those data sets. its far more easy to do those things in SQL than Crystal Reports.
-Sid